# "Edit" link opened in new tab doesn't show error message

Tags: bug, edits, error-message

I've opened a question page and I want to edit it:

1. right-clicked with mouse on "edit" link and opened it in *new tab*.
2. **same page opened** (not "edit" screen).

After that I tried to click on "edit" link right on question page and I saw the reason edit screen cannot be opened (error message):

[image: Error message. Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.]

Should this error message be displayed *also* when edit link opened in new tab and edit screen is not available?